# parse multiple series and rename header in python

Tags: python, pandas, import

My price data looks like this.(snippit of it)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("price.csv", low_memory=False)
print(df.head())

   Unnamed: 0  233740 KS Equity  Unnamed: 2  233160 KS Equity   
0  2015-12-17           10330.0  2017-08-31           10460.0    
1  2015-12-18           10710.0  2017-09-01           10815.0    
2  2015-12-21           10720.0  2017-09-04           10835.0   
3  2015-12-22           10495.0  2017-09-05           10660.0   
4  2015-12-23           10425.0  2017-09-06           10535.0
```

As you'll see the

1. time series starting and end point is different by two columns and
2. There is a empty cell which required to be filled with "date_23340 KS Equity" or something.

I like to import this huge file in efficient manner by equities, and to top it off, change empty cell's name to "date_equities' name". How can I make this out to separate dataframes which consists of dates and values??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `Series` by shift column names, split by first whitespace and append `Date`, last filter only `Unnamed` index values and `rename` columns names:

```
s = df.columns.to_series().shift(-1).str.split(n=1).str[0] + ' Date'
s = s[s.index.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
print (s)
Unnamed: 0    233740 Date
Unnamed: 2    233160 Date
dtype: object

df = df.rename(columns=s)
print (df)
  233740 Date  233740 KS Equity 233160 Date  233160 KS Equity
0  2015-12-17           10330.0  2017-08-31           10460.0
1  2015-12-18           10710.0  2017-09-01           10815.0
2  2015-12-21           10720.0  2017-09-04           10835.0
3  2015-12-22           10495.0  2017-09-05           10660.0
4  2015-12-23           10425.0  2017-09-06           10535.0
```

If need create 2 or 3 columns from all data first create `MultiIndex` by  [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then call [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(n=1, expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename_axis('val').reset_index()
print (df)
      val        Date  KS Equity
0  233160  2017-08-31    10460.0
1  233740  2015-12-17    10330.0
2  233160  2017-09-01    10815.0
3  233740  2015-12-18    10710.0
4  233160  2017-09-04    10835.0
5  233740  2015-12-21    10720.0
6  233160  2017-09-05    10660.0
7  233740  2015-12-22    10495.0
8  233160  2017-09-06    10535.0
9  233740  2015-12-23    10425.0
```

EDIt:

Solution for multiple different headers:

```
#create dummy data
df1 = df.copy()
df1.columns = ['Unnamed: 4','233 JP Equity','Unnamed: 6','235 JP Equity']
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   Unnamed: 0  233740 KS Equity  Unnamed: 2  233160 KS Equity  Unnamed: 4  \
0  2015-12-17           10330.0  2017-08-31           10460.0  2015-12-17   
1  2015-12-18           10710.0  2017-09-01           10815.0  2015-12-18   
2  2015-12-21           10720.0  2017-09-04           10835.0  2015-12-21   
3  2015-12-22           10495.0  2017-09-05           10660.0  2015-12-22   
4  2015-12-23           10425.0  2017-09-06           10535.0  2015-12-23   

   233 JP Equity  Unnamed: 6  235 JP Equity  
0        10330.0  2017-08-31        10460.0  
1        10710.0  2017-09-01        10815.0  
2        10720.0  2017-09-04        10835.0  
3        10495.0  2017-09-05        10660.0  
4        10425.0  2017-09-06        10535.0  

s = df.columns.to_series().shift(-1) + ' Date'
s = s[s.index.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
print (s)
Unnamed: 0    233740 KS Equity Date
Unnamed: 2    233160 KS Equity Date
Unnamed: 4       233 JP Equity Date
Unnamed: 6       235 JP Equity Date
dtype: object

df = df.rename(columns=s)
```

In list comprehension groupby by first number, create dataetimeindex and concat together. Last reshape by `stack` and `unstack` for remove `NaN`s:

```
f = lambda x: x.split(' ',1)[1]
df = pd.concat([x.set_index(x.columns[0]).rename(columns=f) for i, x 
                in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split(n=1).str[0], axis=1)], 1).stack().unstack()
print (df)
            JP Equity  KS Equity
2015-12-17    10330.0    10330.0
2015-12-18    10710.0    10710.0
2015-12-21    10720.0    10720.0
2015-12-22    10495.0    10495.0
2015-12-23    10425.0    10425.0
2017-08-31    10460.0    10460.0
2017-09-01    10815.0    10815.0
2017-09-04    10835.0    10835.0
2017-09-05    10660.0    10660.0
2017-09-06    10535.0    10535.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @jezrael, you are correct till making new column headers. And it works fine. However, there is a small cache that not all equities are end with "KS Equity" There are also some "JP Equity" in the data so the result is,

Comment: `val        Date  JP Equity  KS Equity
0  069500  2013-01-02        NaN    27130.0
1  069660  2013-01-02        NaN    27110.0
2  091160  2013-01-02        NaN    16140.0
3  091170  2013-01-02        NaN     7540.0
4  091180  2013-01-02        NaN    20310.0`

Comment: Maybe I need to facilatate this a little bit more..Thank you so much:)

Comment: @HannahLee - Sure, give me some time.

Comment: @HannahLee - What is expected output if `KS Equity` and `JP Equity` ?  3 columns?

Comment: Well, this should not only be 3 columns, all the equities are separate financial instrument thus, it would be better if I have a 422(which is a number of equities in total) list consists of date and value

Comment: @HannahLee - I edit answer, please check it. It is data dependent thing, so not 100% sure if working with real data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169735/discussion-between-hannah-lee-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not happy with the automatic header generated by pandas from the first line of your file, you can skip it, tell pandas to not generate a header and provide your own.
Besides that, you can choose the columns to read in:

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv("price.csv", usecols = [0,1], skiprows=1, header=['date', 'equity'])

df_2 = pd.read_csv("price.csv", usecols = [2,3], skiprows=1, header=['date', 'equity'])
```